# Tab Bar Controller hiding tabs depending on the Login - Using Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

My application has two types of login: Vendor or Customer.

Depending on the login, the user will have access to some tabs on the Tab bar controller.
Example:
- Vendor: Can access Tab 1, Tab 2 and Tab 3
- Customer: Can access Tab 1 and Tab 2

Trying to implement this I made a UITabBarController class (but the line `customTabBar.items![2].accessibilityElementsHidden` does not hide the tab):

```
import UIKit
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

@IBOutlet weak var customTabBar: UITabBar!

var viewControllerList: [UIViewController]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if SingletonLogin.shared.isVendor {
        customTabBar.items![2].accessibilityElementsHidden // Tries to hide Tab 3
        customTabBar.items![1].title = "Items"
    } else {
        customTabBar.items![1].title = "Favorites"
    }
}
```

This class is linked with a Custom Tab Bar Controller on my Storyboard:

[image]

I am able to do it programmatically, but then I can't use the views on the storyboard.

I would like to find a way to do this using the storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

@IBOutlet weak var customTabBar: UITabBar!

var viewControllerList: [UIViewController]?    // Not required

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if SingletonLogin.shared.isVendor {
        self.viewControllers = [self.viewControllers[0], self.viewControllers[1], self.viewControllers[2]]
    } else {
        self.viewControllers = [self.viewControllers[0], self.viewControllers[1]]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nitish! This was exactly what I was looking for, it works fine now

Comment: Perfect. Happy coding !!